Present perfect usage
The link is https://youtu.be/Nt7O2w1Fpxc?si=TrerrC4ExHijjnWc
This is tv show and what speaker said,strong text
I am losing weight without even thinking about it. Hear this , last Tuesday I forgot to eat lunch. Crazy right? , that never happens. I have forgotten  I have eaten lunch on a number of occasions. So I had to eat again. Just in case.
But this is monumental. I have forgotten to take the gas nozzle out of my car. I have forgotten my gun was loaded. But I have never forgotten lunch. Anyway long story short. You are looking at happy confident  slightly smaller man than you saw in here one week ago. Win the battle here (temple) win the battle here (womb).
I watched this show in youtube.The speaker used present simple ,  past simple , present continuous and present perfect. What I understood "I have forgotten I have eaten lunch on a number of ocassions"
that indicates the recent past may be around the Tuesday or earlier he ate lunch in ocassions. That sentence shows recent past action. Yes I understood like that.
And also "I have forgotten to take the gas  nozzle out of my car. I have forgotten my gun was loaded. I have never forgotten lunch." That sentence indicates present situation by using present perfect.
Is my comprehension right?

There's no comma / pause in I have forgotten [that] I have eaten lunch on a number of occasions. This particular use of Present Perfect has nothing whatsoever to do with "recent past". It doesn't really even imply any particularly close connection between the reported action in the past, and the speaker's current circumstances. The speaker is simply pointing out that over a lifetime, there will have been be many occasions when he's eaten lunch, forgotten that he's eaten, and eaten lunch again, just to make sure he didn't miss a meal.

It's very quirky phrasing, though. He initially says I forgot to eat lunch After that he says he has forgotten [that] he has eaten lunch. Then he says he's never forgotten lunch (by implication, never until last Tuesday). It's hard to keep track of, because it quirkily juxtaposes forgetting to eat lunch, and forgetting having eaten lunch, with the added twist that the words to eat are optional for the first sense (he includes them the first time, but not the second).

I see you've added another unwanted comma in I have forgotten to take the gas , nozzle out of my car as well. Why would you do that? It wouldn't make sense for the speaker to pause there.

Thank you very much sir. @FumbleFingers


last Tuesday I forgot to eat lunch

Explicit time given in the past. Past tense for the verb.

have forgotten I have eaten lunch on a number of occasions.

This is the "experiential" use of the past tense.  It lets you talk about thing that you have experienced in the past, without referring to a particular time.   "I have seen Mt Fuji" or "I have watched Star Wars" are examples of experiences I have had.  They don't refer to something that is "recent".  This is badly phrased, it is not "good English".  It would be better to say "I've forgotten to eat lunch on a number of occasions". This is typical of the kind of mistake that people often make when speaking.

I have forgotten to take the gas nozzle out of my car. I have forgotten my gun was loaded.

More experiences.  Not recent.
As noted in the comments, it is all a bit mixed up and generally not "good English".

Thank you very much. You are always giving precise perspectives.I am glad for this answer. @James K

Please remember to include the link in the original post It seems likely that it is an informal omission of some words, and he intended the meaning "I've forgotten whether or not I'd eaten lunch."  He's making jokes and being deliberately relaxed.  Clever scriptwriters will deliberately include mistakes like this in the script to make it seem more "natural".

This is i watched video link and i did not understand and that i asked https://youtu.be/Nt7O2w1Fpxc?si=TrerrC4ExHijjnWc @James K

As I understand it, your This is badly phrased seems to be saying that I have forgotten I have eaten lunch is substandard, and should be replaced by I've forgotten to eat lunch. But they mean completely different things, and I'd say almost certainly the entire cited text is a complete fabrication purely intended to showcase that contrast (with the added complication that I've forgotten to eat lunch and I've forgotten lunch do in fact mean exactly the same).
